# Android - Fit ImageView to ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, picasso

I want to fit ImageView inside a ListView row so that it fits to the edge of device's screen.

This is my current layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the custom_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img_item"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using Picasso library to load the image. I've tried using .centerCrop, .centerInside and .fit using Picasso's loader option. No luck.

Picasso settings:

```
Picasso.with(context) //
        .load(iim.getResized()) //
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .fit().centerInside()
        .into(vh.item_image);
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Have you try to put ScaleType="centerCrop" in the xml instead of Picasso? maybe this solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

in the xml

Answer (score 1):

in your program use this .centerCrop()

```
Picasso.with(context) //
    .load(iim.getResized()) //
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .centerCrop() //thissss
    .into(vh.item_image);
```

or in your xml:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView height right now is 0dp. You need to set layout_height. Your width is fine.